# Нулевая суффиксация

Tags: словообразование

Запуталась в бессуффиксном образовании отглагольных существительных.
Цепочка «кричать» - «крикнуть» - «крик» понятна. Но от «шуметь» «шум» почему-то не образуется, как указывается в словаре А.Н. Тихонова. Я в отчаянии! «Шум» лишен суффикса? Даже нулевого?! Его совсем нельзя выделять? Почему такая несправедливость?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Схема образования: **шум ― шуметь**, шум ― непроизводное слово, суффикса не имеет. Здесь глагол мотивируется существительным.

Из словаря: ШУМ,  м. 1. обычно ед. Разнообразные звуки, слившиеся в нестройное звучание;

ШУМЕТЬ, 1. Издавать, производить шум (1 зн.)

Comment: Крик - громкий, напряженный звук голоса. Кричать - издавать крик. (Тоже из словаря.) Может быть, тогда и "кричать" от "крик"? Вдруг и "крик" - непроизводное слово, а великие лингвисты ошиблись? Может быть, есть способ отличить непроизводные (например, шум) от производных (например, крик)?

Comment: крик, морфемный состав: http://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=Крик

Answer (score 2):

Это связано с тем, что *кричать (*крикати)* — в диахронии — общеславянское слово, а *крик (*крикъ)* — его отглагольное производное, тогда как слово *шум* является частью пласта индоевропейской лексики и восходит к и.-е. корню  **seu-: *sou-* «приводить в движение, поворачивать, сгибать», то есть появилось раньше и лишь после этого от него образовался глагол **шумěти (шуметь)*.

Короче говоря, в случае с *криком* сначала появился глагол, а затем — уже от него — существительное; с *шумом* же все наоборот: сначала существительное, потом глагол.

В синхронии это неочевидно, поэтому и возникают такие вопросы.

Если вам все-таки очень хочется выделить суффикс в слове *шум*, то выделяйте исторический — *-м*. Нулевого же тут нет — с чего бы ему быть?

**Дополнение**

Вообще, тут возможны два подхода: синхронический и диахронический. Первый заключается в том, что мы рассматриваем *шум* как отглагольное существительное (от *шуметь*) и выделяем нулевой суффикс, однако это неверно с исторической (диахронической) точки зрения, которая описана в моем ответе, а также в словаре Тихонова.

**Как отличить существительное с нулевым суффиксом? (В синхронии.)**

Существительные с нехарактерным для них значением действия или признака являются в русском языке производными, они образованы от глаголов или от прилагательных. Так, значение слова *бег* любой носитель языка объяснит так: «Это когда бегут» (ср. с нашим случаем: «Это когда шумят»).

Для выделения нулевого словообразующего суффикса **необходимы два условия**:

1) слово должно быть производно, мотивировано другим словом языка (поэтому слово *гам* не имеет нулевого суффикса),

2) должно иметься словообразовательное значение, которое может выражаться ненулевым суффиксом,но в данном случае оно материально не выражено: *шум-ø-☐* — *шум-е-ть* (*шум* — существительное со значением абстрактного действия).

Подробнее: http://rusolimp.kopeisk.ru/morfemika/?file=111.

Comment: Возможно, это против правил сайта, но не могу не выразить своего восхищения! ☺

Comment: @ЕленаТаволга всегда рад помочь!

Answer (score 1):

**Шуметь- шум- шумный-шумно.**

В слове "шум" выделяется нулевой суффикс, т.к .оно является производным от "шуметь". Для того чтобы найти в слове нулевой суффикс обычно прибегают к конверсии.Т.е. надо найти однокоренное слово, которое, в отличие от мотивирующего, будет относится к другой части речи,и,если в этом случае, ничего не прибавится к мотивирующему слову, следует говорить о нулевом суффиксе 
**Ср.: золото → золот#ой. шум# (шуметь).**

См. здесь: [Вычленение нулевой морфемы в сфере формо- и словообразования. Нулевая морфема](https://studfiles.net/preview/3558917/page:11/)

Comment: Благодарю за разъяснение и полезную ссылку.)))